# Jackson JSON to stream parser

Tags: java, json, jackson, stream

I would like to process response from HttpRequest (JSON object) as stream. That's mean filter only `data` field which interest me and return it as a stream and process it further (send as HttpServletResponse). I don't want to load it to memory as the `response.body()` might be huge (1 000 000+ lines). Unfortunately I don't see any method on JsonParser class that would return stream.

```
HttpResponse<InputStream> response = client.send(httpRequest, BodyHandlers.ofInputStream());
InputStream result = response.body();
JsonFactory factory = new JsonFactory();
try(JsonParser parser = factory.createParser(result)){
  while (parser.nextToken() != JsonToken.END_OBJECT) {
    if ("data".equals(parser.getCurrentName())) {
      parser.getValueAsString(); // it returns correct lines but as String
    }
  }
}
```

Does anybody know how to handle it? Or maybe I should use some other library/API?

Comment: https://cassiomolin.com/2019/08/19/combining-jackson-streaming-api-with-objectmapper-for-parsing-json/ might be something?

Comment: @Sam I saw it. In this example it's shown how to parse Json Object to some Java object with ObjectMapper or by creating an instance of new Object. My goal is to not load this data to memory (not creating objects) but read it as a Stream and send it further

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You already process the input data as a stream, so it can easily be written to another stream like an `HttpServletResponse`.

Get the outputstream you want to transfer the data to:

```java
ServletOutputStream out = httpServletResponse.getOutputStream();
```

And for each data string, write the value to the new stream:

```java
while ... {
    if ("data".equals(parser.getCurrentName())) {
        String data = parser.getValueAsString();
        out.write(data.getBytes("UTF-8"));
    }
}
```